# Load multiple addin dll files into Autodesk Revit

Tags: add-in, revit-api, revit

I'm installing two instances of my Revit addin. When I run Revit everything is shown correctly in the ribbon panel: two dropdowns - one for each instance.
The problem is that both access the same dll file (the one that is loaded first) even though each path of each addin file leads to a different location.

This is how the addin files look like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <RevitAddIns>
    <AddIn Type="Application">
      <Assembly>C:\A\My.Application.dll</Assembly>
      <ClientId>{GUID1}</ClientId>
      <Name>My Plugin A</Name>
      <FullClassName>My.Application.Application</FullClassName>
    </AddIn>
  </RevitAddIns>
```

and

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <RevitAddIns>
    <AddIn Type="Application">
      <Assembly>C:\B\My.Application.dll</Assembly>
      <ClientId>{GUID2}</ClientId>
      <Name>My Plugin B</Name>
      <FullClassName>My.Application.Application</FullClassName>
    </AddIn>
  </RevitAddIns>
```

I've changed every entry but couldn't get Revit to load two different files.

Any ideas or hints are much appreciated.

Comment: I believe the DLL have their own name and Revit understands that is already loaded. This exists to avoid references being loaded twice.

Comment: Yes, that's what I thought. Do you know any workarounds?

Comment: first, why do you have the same class on the same DLL (and I assume they are equal) loaded twice? if you must, maybe you can change the assembly name... but I haven't tried.

Comment: It's because there are two versions of the plugin. Each depending on another software that is loaded from the plugin.
I have already tried to replace any of the attributes but no success.
I have also tried two different builds with different namespaces, etc. but still no success

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The .NET AppDomain will not load the same class twice. And Revit uses this mechanism.

For you case, I would suggest edit the AssemblyInfo.cs file. First I would suggest you use a different name for each assembly you build (with different versions of your reference). If you must maintain the same name, you can consider different versions so .NET AppDomain loads both. Below are the attributes you should consider change:

```
[assembly: AssemblyTitle("Name01")]
[assembly: AssemblyProduct("Name01")]
[assembly: AssemblyFileVersion("1.0.1")]
[assembly: AssemblyInformationalVersion("1.0.1")]
```

To maintain the same code, you can use [C# Preprocessor Directives](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ed8yd1ha.aspx) and compile both cases (creating both DLLs during build).

Comment: OK. So loading two dlls from different locations that are basically the same is not possible in .NET.
I'll have to find another solution then as there is only one dll version inside my installer.
But thanks a bunch for clarifying.